# WebAPI Response never completes when returning HttpResponseMessage and Application Insights is configured

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

I have an MVC5/WebAPI2 application which has had Application Insights enabled since I created the web project.

WebApi methods that return objects (e.g. string, model objects) are returned as expected - serialized into JSON or XML.

```
 public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    async public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReadString(int id) {

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();

        string str;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://someurl.com/resource.rss");
            str = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        }

        response.Content = new StringContent(str);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = str.Length;

        return response;
    }
}
```

When I created an action that returns an HttpResponseMessage, I noticed a strange behavior in the browser (tested with Chrome and IE).  Specifically, my content was returned to the browser, but the "busy" indicator never stopped spinning until I hit the Stop button, or stopped the web server (Visual Studio 2013).

I've verified that the method above works as expected in a web app without Application Insights.  Specifically, once the data is returned to the browser, the response ends.  When the method below is added to a freshly-created app with Application Insights, the behavior described previously is encountered.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This appears to be an ASP.NET bug triggered by the instrumentation code added by Application Insights. I have created a bug in our internal issue tracking system and will post an update here once it's fixed or if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a `NullReferenceException` thrown in the ASP.NET request pipeline. The Microsoft.ApplictionInsights.Web package is handling the [HttpApplication.PreSendRequestHeaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.presendrequestheaders.aspx) event, which triggers the problem. In the upcoming 0.17 release we have changed the Application Insights code to no longer handle this event and you shouldn't see this problem anymore.