# Web API Response never completes when returning HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270440/webapi-response-never-completes-when-returning-httpresponsemessage-and-applicati), an `HttpResponseMessage` never completes when returning manually formatted html from Web API. All content is transmitted correctly, but the response doesn't close and the browser load-wheel keeps spinning.

The difference is that I'm not using Application Insights.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetHtml(string id)
{
    var asset = await ...

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
    // ...

    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent(builder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
    };
}
```

This html is not intended for browser consumption, but for Excel data imports. Just like the browser, Excel can't fetch the data because it doesn't complete.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Using a custom `MediaTypeFormatter` works. Documentation [here.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters)

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, builder.ToString(), new HTMLFormatter(), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Not posting as an answer as I can't tell why that is.

**UPDATE 2**

When removing the repository call to fetch db records and simply returning a mock html document, the http response closes correctly. No exceptions thrown and the db records are retrieved correctly. Dependencies are resolved by Unity.

Comment: Similar to the answer on the linked question, are there any exceptions being thrown from your Web API application while the request is processing? (You can see thrown exceptions in your Output window.)

Comment: No exceptions, but I noticed it happens usually on the second request from the same browser tab, i.e. a refresh. The controller action completes and returns. The thread exit codes are 259 "STILL_ACTIVE".

Comment: When I return `IHttpActionResult` instead, it works fine, but the content type is wrong of course.

Comment: Can you break the debugger while the request is hanging and try to ascertain from the call stack what stage of the pipeline it's stuck in?

Comment: "Code not running." after returning, but the browser still spins. Maybe it's a caching or header issue... ? This is not an issue when using a MediaFormatter, see update above.

Comment: @BenjaminE.: Do you have a call to `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait` further up your call stack?

Comment: @StephenCleary No, just the async call to the repository. When removing that call, the response closes correctly. The database records are fetched correctly when the async call is there.

Comment: @AdrianHofman I do see a few first chance `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException` when the solution loads, but not during the api call. Dependencies resolve fine however.

Comment: Hmm, you don't have a Telerik extension installed perchance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472568/visual-studio-2012-source-not-available-code-not-running-while-debugging-win

Comment: @AdrianHofman No. A possibility would be the db driver which is MongoDB. Only when calling the db it fails.